# Change code to get it working in sh or ash

Tags: shell, scripting, sh, ash

I wrote a function to read the time from a config file and calculate it to seconds.

The line in the config file looks like that:

```
timeend=30h
```

The function was written in for bash, but in the Linux Distro I use there's no bash avalaible, only sh and ash.

In sh and ash, it seems that I can't use the `-1`.
How do I need to change the code to get it working in ash or sh?

```
getTimeEndFromConfig(){
case $timeend in
*s )
echo ${timeend::-1};;
*m )
zeit=${timeend::-1}
TIMEEND=$(($zeit*60))
echo ${TIMEEND};;
*h )
zeit=${timeend::-1}
TIMEEND=$(($zeit*3600))
echo ${TIMEEND};;
esac
}
```

**Update**
So I changed it, but now I always get an `arithmetic syntax error` when I call the funtion.

Comment: You _changed it_ to what? Which version of `sh` do you use?

Answer (score 0):

`${timeend::-1}` is a bash extension (in fact a relatively recent one with negative offsets).

[POSIX shell supports the following syntax](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html):

```
zeit=${timeend%?}
```

In this context, `?` means any character and the `%` means remove the shortest occurrence of the pattern from the end of the string.

Alternatively, you could use sed:

```
zeit=$(printf '%s' "$timeend" | sed 's/.$//')
```

This also removes the last character from the string.

In older shells that doesn't support the arithmetic expansion, I'd suggest going with awk:

```
echo "$(printf '%d' "${timeend%?}" | awk '{print $1 * 3600 }')"
```

Here I combined the substring extraction and the multiplication in the final branch of your `case` statement.

Comment: Or just `zeit=${timeend%?}`

Comment: @tripleee didn't realise that worked in POSIX shell but if it does, then yes!

Comment: It absolutely does.  The `%%` variant is a Bash extension but plain old `%` and its sister `#` are definitely in POSIX.

Comment: @tripleee by the way, looking at the reference I found, it seems like `%%` is also supported in POSIX.

Comment: If I call the function, after I changed it, I always get an arithmetic syntax error. Is the calculation syntax also not supported?

Comment: Yup, you'll need to use `bc` or Awk or `expr`.  Traditionally, `expr` would be the simplest and most idiomatic of these, but it's kind of horrible.

Comment: Thanks for the POSIX reference, and apologies for the misleading tangent.

Comment: Both POSIX `sh` and (according to [this](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ash)) `ash` support `$((...))` for arithmetic expressions.

Comment: @chepner I thought so too - I guess that the syntax hasn't been around forever though, so maybe it's not supported on the OP's version.

Comment: The fact that the error reads `arithmetic syntax error` implies that the shell understands `$((...))`; it just doesn't understand what's inside. I'd examine the resulting value of `zeit` more closely to make sure it really is just a number.